# How to take the gradient of the dipole dipole interaction energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, dipole

This answer ([Force between two point dipoles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160649/force-between-two-point-dipoles)) was very clear; however, I am having trouble understanding how to take the gradient of $$U = \frac{p′⋅p}{r^3}−\frac{3(p′⋅\vec{r})(p⋅\vec{r})}{r^5}.$$ with respect to $\vec{r}$. Can anyone please explain how this is done? I have tried and failed several times to simplify. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try it using index notation? That’s usually easier.

Comment: I am unsure how to do that in spherical coordinates.

Comment: You work in Cartesian components using the Einstein summation convention. You write $\nabla$ as $\partial_i$, $r$ as $(x_jx_j)^{1/2}$, $\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r}$ as $p_kx_k$ and use $\partial_ix_j=\delta_{ij}$. If this makes no sense, ignore it; you’ll learn index notation later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two nontrivial things you need are

$$\nabla r=\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$$

and

$$\nabla(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{r})=\vec{a}.$$

You can show these using

$$r=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2},$$

$$\vec{r}=x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}+z\hat{z},$$

and

$$\nabla=\hat{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\hat{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\hat{z}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}.$$

The rest is just using

$$\nabla\frac{1}{r^n}=-\frac{n}{r^{n+1}}\nabla r=-\frac{n\vec{r}}{r^{n+2}}$$

and the product rule for gradients. You'll get something with various terms combining $\vec{r}$, $\vec{p}$, and $\vec{p}'$. I'm not sure what you are expecting it to simplify to.