# Force between two dipoles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, dipole, dipole-moment

I am extremelly confused with this question: Basically suppose we have two electric dipoles, parallel to each other, as follows in the figure:
[image]

I am supposed to show that the force is attractive and radial. But I am not getting how it can be radial (pointing toward each other)!!

See, the force acting on a dipole is $$\vec F = (\vec p \cdot \vec \nabla ) \vec E$$

So the force is parallel to the electric field. Let's consider the force acting on $P1$ due to $P2$

But, here, $$E = \frac{-p_2}{4 \pi \epsilon r^3} \hat z$$

And, since $\hat z$ is constant, $(\vec p \cdot \vec \nabla)$ will not alter its direction, so the force is also in z direction !?

Comment: Does [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160649/211658) help answering your question.

Comment: Electric field of a dipole is definitely not everywhere directed along the dipole axis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole#/media/File:VFPt_dipole_electric.svg

Comment: You are just using incorrect formula for the electric field (probably you simply took the value on the axis). It is quite easy to derive the electric field of a dipole yourself, thinking of it as two charges $+q, -q$ at distance $d$, so that the dipole moment is $p=qd$, and then taking the limit $d\rightarrow 0$ while keeping $p$ constant.

Comment: $(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{\nabla})\vec{E}$ is not in general parallel to $\vec{E}$.

Comment: The force is repulsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, $(\vec{p} \cdot \vec{\nabla}) \vec{E}$ is not necessarily parallel to $\vec{E}$. For example, if $\vec{p}$ is in the $z$-direction, then$$(\vec{p} \cdot \vec{\nabla}) \vec{E} = p_z \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial z} = p_z \left(  \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial z} \hat{x} + \frac{\partial E_y}{\partial z} \hat{y} +\frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z} \hat{z} \right)$$and this expression can easily have $x$- or $y$-components even if $E_x = E_y = 0$ at a particular point.

Comment: Oh. Got it. Thank you